# One page of a website refuses to load in IE9 only on some machines.

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

This issue just started happening last week and for the life of me I can't figure out why or what is causing it. Only on some machines people who are using Internet Explorer 9 can't get to a registration page.

The website is http://www.sweepstakes.com then try to hit an enter or enter now button, it should take you to a registration form. It works on all browsers and a lot of the times on IE9, but for some reason some machines can not get to it. They have cleared cache/web history/enabled cookies etc.

The only error the page loads to is an "Internet Explorer Cannot Display the webpage" error and that's that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: yeah, rell really going to click on www.sweepstakes.com....

Comment: I don't want or need anyone to sign up, it's an issue just getting to the registration page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I clicked on the *Enter Now* button for the first time, it took very long to load the page. I would try to check performance to prevent request timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Press F12 in IE9 to show the developer tools and enable debugging. It may point you in the right direction as to where the problem lies. Failing that check your web server logs to see if any errors are being shown.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a IE9-configuration or machine-specific issue - unless clicking the button in IE9 on affected machines *sometimes* yields the page as expected (in which case I think that "well-timed" timeouts due to intermittently poor server performance is a possibility).  (Clicking the button in a non-IE9 browser on affected machines should shed light on the possibility of server-related timeouts.)

I had a similar issue due to an add-on in IE9: by disabling all add-ons then re-enabling them one-by-one, I was able to find the offender and disable it for good.

Other possibilities mentioned in TechNet Forums (e.g. in [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieitprocurrentver/thread/0ebfd15a-3c18-41cb-ba0e-9c8997cdf922)) seem worth checking out too, including but not limited to:

- "Preserve Favorites website data" being checked in IE9's Delete Browsing History
- Tracking Protection being enabled under IE9's "Manage add-ons"
- ("well-timed") DNS(-caching) issues

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line.  I had an issue with DOM elements doing funky things in all IE versions.  Removing this line helped.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

This shouldn't affect the rest of the site; and I do not have a good suggestion for why this does that.  There has to be an explanation; but I didn't have time to do the research.